# web2py - queued e-mails not send via tls encrypted smtp server

Tags: web2py

Since I am sending several e-mails upon form submission in my web2py-application, I would like to queue those and send via a separate script.
I have followed the instructions from the web2py book and it seems to work fine, until I use a tls encrypted smtp server.
If I don't queue the e-mails in a database and send the e-mails via the controller, the e-mails are send out properly.
Queueing into the database works fine, including status updates.

Why would sending out e-mails from database fail when using tls encrypted smtp server? Again, the server settings and sending out e-mails directly from controller works fine, but queueing it in database and sending via script fails (only when using tls-encrypted smtp server).

Edit:
The error message I get is: WARNING web2py.Mail.send failure: Connection unexpectedly closed.

Anyone else encountered this?

Many thanks!
A.

Below is my code:

In controller:

```
def contact():
    form = SQLFORM(db.contact, formstyle='bootstrap3_stacked')
    form.append(Recaptcha2(public_key='', private_key=''))
    form.element('textarea[name=Your_message]')['_style'] = 'resize:none;'
    for label in form.elements('label'):
        label["_style"] = "display:none;"
    if form.process().accepted:
        requester = str(form.vars.email)
        db.queue.insert(status='pending',
        email='email@test.com',
        subject = '123',
        massege = 'xyz') #massege is not a spelling mistake
        db.queue.insert(status='pending',
        email= str(form.vars.email),
        subject = '123',
        massege = 'xyz')
    return dict(form=form)
```

My model file:

```
from gluon.tools import Mail
from gluon.tools import Recaptcha2
mail2 = Mail() #using mail2, since I am using different instances of Mail() for different e-mails/smtp's throughout the application
mail2.settings.server = 'smtp.office365.com:587' or 'logging'
mail2.settings.sender = 'lala@lala.com'
mail2.settings.login = 'lala@lala.com:myPSWD'
mail2.settings.tls = myconf.get('smtp.tls')

db.define_table('queue', Field('status'), Field('email'), Field('subject'), Field('massege'))
```

This is the mail_queue.py script (from web2py book)

```
import time

while True:
    rows = db(db.queue.status == 'pending').select()
    for row in rows:
        if mail2.send(to=row.email,
        subject = row.subject,
        message = row.massege): #massege is not a spelling mistake
            row.update_record(status='sent')
        else:
            row.update_record(status='failed')
        db.commit()
    time.sleep(180)
```

This is how I call the mail_queue.py script - specifying -N throws an error (no such option -N)
$ python web2py.py -S myapp -M -R applications/myapp/private/mail_queue.py

Comment: Do all messages fail when queued? I believe Office 365 limits you to 30 messages per minute -- is it possible you are exceeding that limit?

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks! The only messages that are not send are the ones that I aim to send out via office365 - however, when I do not queue those but send directly from controller, they are send (it takes however several seconds, which is why I wanted to queue those). If I use another smtp server (i.e. mail.com) it works fine (not tls encrypted). I am way below 30 messages per minute. Could it be that connecting to office smtp takes too long and thus fail when queuing, but works when sending from controller?

Comment: Do _all_ messages fail or only some? Note, you would only have to exceed 30 messages per 180 seconds to hit the Office 365 limit, as the module code runs only every 180 seconds and sends all messages accumulated in the queue. Anyway, to help diagnose, maybe try adding a `result` JSON-type field to `db.queue`. When a send fails, do: `row.update_record(status=failed, result=dict(result=mail2.result, error=mail2.error))`.

Comment: All messages failed - I am testing on 2 messages only. For whatever reason I can't seem to change the server anymore - by that I mean that all mails continue to be sent through mail.com (mail=Mail()), despite me having removed the respective code from the model file. It still keeps sending e-mails from that server. I can't change it to send it through office365 (mail2=Mail(); in the mail_queue.py script I am using mail2.send), which caused it to fail. I have deleted browser history but nothing

Comment: Also, when I try and use two different smtp servers in one controller (i.e. send one type of e-mail through mail2.send, and the other through mail.send, it sends both e-mails through the server specified under mail=Mail() - any idea what is happening?

Comment: Is your app compiled on the server? If so, changing the source files will have no effect on the running code. You have to remove the compiled version (there is an option for that in admin) and re-compile (actually, while testing, it will be easier to use the non-compiled code so you can make quick changes). If that isn't the issue, then it is hard to say without seeing all the code -- what you describe is not really possible, so presumably some information is missing here.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - The app is deployed on Pythonanywhere - in the past I have used either Pythonanywhere or the admin interface to make changes to the source files without any apparent issue. I agree, what I describe is odd, though that is the behavior I encounter - I am happy to update and post more code; not sure what other code would be helpful here.

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you -- clearly the code you are editing is not the code that is running. Maybe try a fresh installation on a different server or try to get some help from Pythonanywhere.

Comment: Thanks again for input - appreciate it. I will ask the guys at Pythonanywhere also. I don't seem to have apparent flaws in the code I posted, and I can edit other code in the controller (i.e. uncomment the Recaptcha2 form.append..., in the same controller and it stops showing on page).

Answer (score 0):

I followed Anthony's advice and made a fresh install of my app.
Though I don't know why I encountered issues previously, I can now send queued e-mails through tls-encrypted server (here office365) without problems.
Also, editing the code and switching between different servers works fine.